# Apache Spark filter list column in dataset based on overlap with another set in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

Imagine simple test:

```
@Test
public void testIfColumnHasMentionsInPrimaryKeys() {
    List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create("ID, ID1"),
            RowFactory.create("ID,COLUMN_UNDERSCORE_1"),
            RowFactory.create("ID1, ID2")
    );

    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
            new StructField("COLUMN", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty())
    });
    Dataset<Row> rows = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

    Set<String> primaryKeys = new HashSet<>();
    primaryKeys.add("ID1");
    primaryKeys.add("ID2");

    RegexTokenizer regexTokenizer = new RegexTokenizer().setInputCol("COLUMN")
            .setOutputCol("COLUMN_AS_LIST").setToLowercase(false).setPattern("\\s*,\\s*");
    Dataset<Row> transformedRows = regexTokenizer.transform(rows);

    transformedRows.show();
}
```

The question is: what to do next in order to check if at least 1 value in `COLUMN_AS_LIST` mentioned in `primaryKeys`. `Columns.isin()` works for a single value in column and `Column.contains()` - for a single value in braces, while I need to find based on intersection (if exists). Any ideas, please?

**UPDATE**: There is an option like:

```
Dataset<Row> filter = transformedRows.filter(e -> e.getList(1).stream().anyMatch(primaryKeys::contains));
```

But it looks ugly, isn't it?

Comment: `But it looks ugly, isn't it?` welcome to Streams lol. You might want to check out codereview.stackexchange.com, they're always good at suggesting better ways to do things.

Comment: It's it not I don't like streams and lambdas, but this solution assumes transformer always adds column to the end of the dataset (as getList is only accessed by index) and that doesn't seem to be solid.